# Enterprise Library Exception handling and async callbacks

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, exception, callback, enterprise-library

I'm running a small console app that makes some web service calls asynchronously.  As you know, this involves a callback method being called once the async method is complete.

This app was previously doing synchronous calls and using EntLib 5.0 to apply an exception handling policy to all of the app.  The call was quite simple:

```
            ExceptionManager em = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<ExceptionManager>();
            try
            {
                // Call main work method
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                em.HandleException(ex, "Main Policy");
                WriteErrorToConsole(ex);
            }
```

Nice, concise, and in one place.  But now I have an async callback, and it's not in the same stack.

In order to achieve consistent error handling, do I need to repeat this pattern in my callback method?  If I had multiple async calls and callback methods, would I have to do it in every single method, or is there some way to apply an EntLib error-handling policy to all of them?

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5, 4.0, or 4.5? If on 4.5, the async/await stuff should let you write this fairly naturally. If not, there's some thinking to do.

Comment: @ChrisTavares  I'm using 4.0.

Comment: @ChrisTavares  Can you point me in a good direction?  I have something that's working (ExceptionManager use in the callback method) but I'm now facing the need to signal the main app if something goes wrong in the callback.  I can imagine a solution, but the code is starting to be a) complex, and b) brittle.

Comment: @AnnL I don't think any support for async operations in EHAB would address the need to communicate the app that something failed, because the details of how that would happen are specific to your app. What it could do is to wrap your app-specific callback so that you don't have to write the boilerplate code, though. Btw, the complete pattern for using the EHAB, which includes a rethrow check, is described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664488(v=pandp.50).aspx.